# Powershell: split string with newline, then use -contains

Tags: powershell

```
$a = {aa
bb
cc}
$a = $a -split "`n"
$a -contains "aa"
```

This returns false, when the string "aa" is seemingly part of the list. Why is this?

Comment: Even though your question seem obvious, it will be of help you do edit it so as to elaborate further; what are you trying to achieve, etc.

Comment: Why on earth are you splitting a scriptblock? (And hint: you're a programmer in an interactive shell. PowerShell is not lying when it returns false, which means `aa` is not part of the list, which means you should be poking at what the list contains. `($a -split "\`n")[0].Length` => `3` for example)

Comment: -Contains is a list operator (does the list contain an item).  You want -like, -match, or .Contains() (a string method) to do what you're looking for.

Comment: @MikeShepard: The OP's use of a _script block_ that is converted to a _multi-line string_ is unusual, but the code does work as-is if the script block is defined in the regular console (which uses LF-only line endings) - paste it and execute it to see. By contrast, it won't work if the code is defined in a script that uses CRLF line endings.

Comment: @mklement0 - I should learn to read people's code closer.  I saw string and -contains and jumped to the conclusion (which is usually correct) that they were using the wrong operator.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Didn't have the knowledge I needed to poke around. A colleague pointed me towards the "| clip" command, which showed the extra newline character. Thanks for the comment, you nailed the root cause.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To complement [Kory Gill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216059/45375), which suggests that the **problem may be that the input has CRLF (`` "`r`n" ``) line endings**, in which case `` -split "`n" `` (splitting by LF only) would leave the resulting array elements with a trailing CR (`` "`r" ``), causing `"aa"` not to be found with `-contains`, because the actual value is `` "aa`r" ``.

The ***generic* way to handle input with Windows- *or* Unix-style line endings** is to use:

```
$a -split '\r?\n' # split $a into lines, whether it has CRLF or LF-only line endings
```

<sup>The [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) uses [*regexes* (regular expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), and regex `\r?\n` matches any LF (`\n`) possibly (`?`) preceded by a CR (`\r`). To also match (rare) CR-only newlines, use `\r?\n|\r`

*Regex* escape sequences `\r` and `\n` correspond to *PowerShell* escape sequences `` `r `` and `` `n `` (which work in *double-quoted* strings only).</sup>

Note that PowerShell itself is quite flexible when it comes to line endings:

- Even on Windows ***interactive* input in the regular console uses LF-only line endings (`\n`)** (except in the [obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) ISE).
- Scripts are allowed to have CRLF (`\r\n`) or LF (`\n`) line endings, and **PowerShell *preserves* the source file's line endings in any multi-line string literals defined in the file.**

  - Note that this applies even to multi-line *script blocks*, as in the question: when you convert such a script block to a *string* later - which simply returns everything between the script-block delimiters, `{` and `}` - the source file's line endings are reflected in the resulting string.

---

As an aside: **`[Environment]::NewLine`** contains the **platform-appropriate newline (line-ending) sequence**: `` "`r`n" `` on Windows, `` "`n" `` on Unix-like platforms, but, as discussed above, **there's no guarantee that all input encountered will have platform-appropriate newlines**.

Answer (score 6):

a solution cross Platform:

```
$a = $a -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: While knowing about `[Environment]::NewLine` is helpful, using it with `-split` is not a true cross-platform solution, because you need to be prepared to handle _either_ type of line ending, given that it is not  guaranteed that you'll only encounter platform-native ones.
For instance, if you define a multi-line string in the regular PowerShell console _on Windows_, it will have _LF-only_ line endings, and `-split [Environment]::NewLine` will find no lines and return the entire input string as a one-element array.

Answer (score 4):

Every time I see a `n in code, I always question whether it should be `r`n on Windows.

Change your code to this:

```
$a = $a -split "`r`n"
```

Comment: Or split on _any_ whitespace character: `$a -split "[\s]+"`

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF: `'\s+'` would do, but note that the OP's intent is to split into _lines_, not by any run of whitespace.