# How to get actual separate lines in PowerShell's Write-Output using a newline character

Tags: bash, powershell, grep, select-string

I tried to create a multiline Input to practice `Select-String`, expecting only a single matching line to be output, like I would normaly see it in an `echo -e ... | grep` combination. But the following command still gives me both lines. It seems to be the newline is only interpreted on final ouptut and `Select-String` still gets a single line of input

```
Write-Output "Hi`nthere" | Select-String -Pattern "i"
#
# Hi
# there
#
#
```

while I would expect it to return just

```
Hi
```

I used this version of PowerShell:

```
Get-Host | Select-Object Version
# 5.1.19041.906
```

Comparing with `bash` I would do the following for testing commands on multiline input in bash. I usually generate multiple lines with `echo -e` and then `grep` processes the individual lines.

```sh
echo -e "Hi\nthere" | grep "i"
# Hi
```

**I hope someone can explain what I miss here in PowerShell?** This problem seems like a basic misconception to me, where I also was not sure what to Google for.

### Edits

**[edit 1]:** problem also for line ending with carriage return

```
Write-Output "Hi`r`nthere" | Select-String -Pattern "i"
```

I saw that separating with commas works as valid multiline input. So maybe the question is how to convert from newline to actual input line separation.

```
Write-Output "Hi","there" | Select-String -Pattern "i"
# Hi
```

**[edit 2]:** from **edit  1** I found [this stackoverflow-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252621/2195180), where for me it now works with

```
Write-Output "Hi`nthere".Split([Environment]::NewLine) | Select-String -Pattern "i"
# or
Write-Output "Hi`nthere".Split("`n") | Select-String -Pattern "i"
```

Still may someone please explain why this is relevant here, but not in `bash`?

Comment: `echo -e …` in bash: `-e` means _Enable interpretation of [some backslash-escaped characters](https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html)_. PowerShell equivalent (roughly, incomplete):  ```Write-Output ("Hi`nthere" -split "`r|`n") | Select-String -Pattern "i"```

Comment: `Select-String operates on its input objects individually`, which means that for your purposes you need to split the multiline string into individual lines first using ``(("Hi`nthere" -split '\r?\n') | Select-String -Pattern "i").Line``.  
For an explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374303/9898643)

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ and @Theo and especially @JosefZ for pointing me towards the detailed explanation of "-e" which seems to be the actual explanation I was looking for. So `-e` in bash is equivalent to `-split "\`r|\`\n")`

Comment: Rethinking this... I actually favor `-split "\`r?\`n" more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information is in the comments, but let me summarize and complement it:

**PowerShell's pipeline is *object*-based, and [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) operates on each input object** - even if that happens to be a *single multi-line string object*, such as output by `` Write-Output "Hi`nthere" ``

- **It is only the output from *external programs* that is streamed *line by line*.**

Therefore, **you must split your multi-line string into individual lines** in order to match them as such.

The **best idiom for that is `-split '\r?\n'`**, because it recognizes both Windows-format CRLF and Unix-format LF-only newlines :

```
"Hi`nthere" -split '\r?\n' | Select-String -Pattern "i"
```

Note:

- I've omitted `Write-Output` in favor of PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for more information).
- For more information on how `-split '\r?\n'` works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216677/45375).
- `Select-String` doesn't *directly* output the matching lines (strings); instead it wraps them in [match-information objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) that provide metadata about each match. To get just the matching line (string):

  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, add the `-Raw` switch.
  - In *Windows PowerShell*, pipe to `ForEach-Object Line` or wrap the entire call in `(...).Line`